# Crosstab with the same variables in rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statistics, crosstab

I have the following dataframe:

```
       A      B     C
0   True  False  True
1  False   True  True
2   True   True  True
3   True  False  True
```

I want to find the number of each combination for `'A'`, `'B'` and `'C'`. For example, if I have `True` for `'A'` and `'C'` in the first, third and fourth rows the number is equal to 3.

**Expected output:**

```
   A  B  C
A  3  1  3
B  1  2  2
C  3  2  4
```

I don't have any idea how I can achieve this with Pandas. Maybe you can also tell me if this crosstab has a special name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add to @Andy L.'s answer- you don't have to convert dataframe to `numpy`:

```py
df=df.astype(int)
res=df.T@df
```

Outputs:

```py
   A  B  C
A  3  1  3
B  1  2  2
C  3  2  4
```

Answer (score 4):

Try numpy. It is `np.inner`

```
arr = df.astype(int).T.to_numpy()
np.inner(arr, arr)

Out[1158]:
array([[3, 1, 3],
       [1, 2, 2],
       [3, 2, 4]])

df_final = pd.DataFrame(np.inner(arr, arr), columns=df.columns, index=df.columns)

Out[1160]:
   A  B  C
A  3  1  3
B  1  2  2
C  3  2  4
```